# How to Store string data type value in date data type

Tags: java

I am trying to store string in date data type but I am not finding any solution

```
String string = "20171218";
try {
      DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
      Date dateto=dateformat.parse(string); // convert stringDate to matching Date format
      String parsed = dateformat.format(dateto);
      System.out.println(parsed);

} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

On my above code my date is conversting again to string data type but, i want to store my date to Date data type

EX:
Instead of `String parsed = dateformat.format(dateto);`
I want to store as `Date parsed = dateformat.format(dateto);`, how to do work around for this

Comment: A blank `catch` block is never a good idea.  If there is an exception, it will silently ignore it and you won't know that an exception occurred.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a print statement but my Main concern is regarding conversion.

Comment: But you've already shown the code to convert it.  What on earth are you asking?

Comment: I parsed to String data type String parsed = dateformat.format(dateto);  I want it in Date data type

Comment: `dateto` **is** the date.

Comment: I am getting date as Mon Dec 18 00:00:00 PST 2017 but I want date as 20171218

Comment: Getting **where**? `Date` object can have numerous text representations.  The value stays the same.

Comment: When I am trying to print dateto

Comment: So you want a Date?  Or you want the String `"20171218"`?  Which is it?

Comment: I want dateto in  yyyyMMdd format

Comment: @sande Core concept: **A date-time object such as `java.util.Date` does *not* have a “format”.** Only strings have a format. And please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been explained many many many times already.

Comment: @sande, it sounds like you're saying you want a `String` - the `String` `"20171218"`.  Please remember that a `Date` is _just_ a moment in time - nothing else.  It doesn't have numbers or characters inside.  It doesn't have a timezone.  It doesn't have a format.  So you _can't_ have a `Date` with a `yyyyMMdd` format.  That simply doesn't exist.  You can have a `Date`, or you can have a `String` with a value like `"20171218"`.  They are two entirely different things.

Comment: Having said all that, if you ask Java to print a `Date`, and you don't convert it to a `String` first, you'll get something printed - but it's the result of the internals of Java applying a guess as to what you want to see.  That's when you get something that looks like `"Mon Dec 18 00:00:00 PST 2017"`. That doesn't mean that those characters are part of the `Date` - they're not.  They're simply how Java chooses to display dates, if you don't specify a different way to have them displayed.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "20171218" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE 
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy.

Also, you are inappropriately trying to represent a date-only value with a date + time-of-day type (`java.util.Date`).

## Details

Use modern java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ;  // Built-in, pre-defined. 
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "20171218" , f ) ;
```

## Strings

**Date-time objects do not have a “format”.** Do not conflate strings representing the object’s value with the object itself. An object can generate a string to represent its value, and can parse a string to gain a value, but the object and string are distinct and separate.

Generate a string is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by calling `toString`.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2017-12-18

To generate a string in the same format as your input, call `format`.

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

> 20171218

The “basic” seen above refers to the [type of ISO 8601 formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles) where the use of delimiters is minimized. I suggest you generally use the expanded formats where possible, in this case `2017-12-18`. These expanded formats are used by default throughout the java.time classes when parsing/generating strings.

To generate strings in other formats, search Stack Overflow for info about [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

### `DateTimeParseException`

To catch invalid inputs while parsing, trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
try {
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ;
    LocalDate.parse( "20171218" , f ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … handle exception
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).